# Cannot check out the mit-ros-pkg code

Tags: ros, rosinstall, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try step 5  "rosinstall ~/kinect_demos /opt/ros/diamondback kinect_demos.rosinstall"(http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/dback), then the error information as below:

```
root@ubuntu:~# rosinstall ~/kinect_demos /opt/ros/diamondback kinect_demos.rosinstall
rosinstall operating on /home/tansir/kinect_demos from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/diamondback, kinect_demos.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing /home/tansir/kinect_demos/.rosinstall
[perception_pcl_addons] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/trunk (None) to /home/tansir/kinect_demos/perception_pcl_addons
[perception_pcl_addons] Done.
[mit-ros-pkg] Installing https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk (None) to /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'svn co  "https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk" /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg'
 errcode: 1:
svn: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svn: warning: environment variable LANG is en_US.UTF-8
svn: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.csail.mit.edu:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: svn.csail.mit.edu
 - Valid: from Wed, 15 Jun 2011 13:29:37 GMT until Thu, 14 Jun 2012 13:29:37 GMT
 - Issuer: MIT Computer Science & Artificial Intelligence Lab, Cambridge, Massachusetts, US
 - Fingerprint: f2:1b:58:1c:eb:c1:a2:ed:ea:fc:87:96:f0:fa:80:92:59:ae:27:92
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://svn.csail.mit.edu)
[/vcstools]
[mit-ros-pkg-experimental] Installing https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/branches/sandbox (None) to /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental

WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'svn co  "https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/branches/sandbox" /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental'
 errcode: 1:
svn: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svn: warning: environment variable LANG is en_US.UTF-8
svn: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.csail.mit.edu:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: svn.csail.mit.edu
 - Valid: from Wed, 15 Jun 2011 13:29:37 GMT until Thu, 14 Jun 2012 13:29:37 GMT
 - Issuer: MIT Computer Science & Artificial Intelligence Lab, Cambridge, Massachusetts, US
 - Fingerprint: f2:1b:58:1c:eb:c1:a2:ed:ea:fc:87:96:f0:fa:80:92:59:ae:27:92
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/branches/sandbox': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://svn.csail.mit.edu)
[/vcstools]
[motion_planning_common] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/tags/unstable (None) to /home/tansir/kinect_demos/motion_planning_common
[motion_planning_common] Done.
exception caught Error processing 'mit-ros-pkg' : [mit-ros-pkg] Checkout of https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk version None into /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg failed.
Error processing 'mit-ros-pkg-experimental' : [mit-ros-pkg-experimental] Checkout of https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/branches/sandbox version None into /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'mit-ros-pkg' : [mit-ros-pkg] Checkout of https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk version None into /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg failed.
Error processing 'mit-ros-pkg-experimental' : [mit-ros-pkg-experimental] Checkout of https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/branches/sandbox version None into /home/tansir/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental failed.
```

Can anybody help me , thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31566/cannot-check-out-the-mit-ros-pkg-code/) by [eminem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2158/eminem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to accept the unvalidated ssl certificate.

The easiest way to do this is to manually check something out from the url accept the certification permanently and then rosinstall will be able to call svn for you.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2